# What is the difference in meaning between the sentences?

Tags: articles

"She works in the paper business."
"She works in paper business."

Comment: You might get better response at ell.stackexchange.com. Also, the primary difference is that the second one isn't grammatical, so most native speakers would have a hard time judging the difference in meaning.

Comment: It's normally ***the** XXX business* because you're identifying a particular type of business, but I think you could reasonably (if somewhat uncommonly) say *"She works in international business"* because the referent there is much more vague. But even that one would require an article if we change it slightly to *"She works in **the** international business **sector**"*.